# Query sent from nodejs server to postgres never times out

Tags: postgresql, postgis, connection-pooling, pgadmin, pg

I have a SQL query that I am sending from the server side of my application and it seems to never time out. I am doing `set statement_timeout TO 30000` in the beginning of my query, but that never works. Here is an example query:

`set statement_timeout TO 30000; SELECT t1."building_id", t1."company_name", t1."secondary_name", t1."latitude", t1."longitude"
FROM public."businesses" t1 JOIN (
      SELECT name, (ST_Dump(geom)).geom as geom
      FROM public."us_states") t2
      ON ST_Intersects(t1.geom, t2.geom) WHERE (t2."name" = 'California')`

The query runs fine when I do a normal query, without a geospatial join, but something like the query above never times out. I also tried to add `connectionTimeoutMillis` and `idleTimeoutMillis` to my connection string, but that doesn't work either. Here is how i'm doing my connection to postgres:

```
const { Pool } = require("pg");

var config = {
    user: username,
    database: database,
    password: password,
    host: host,
    connectionTimeoutMillis: 30000,
};

// Postgres Connection
var client = new Pool(config);
client.connect();

client.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('something bad has happened!', err.stack);
});

module.exports = {
    queryPostgres: function (sql, cb) {
        var query = client.query(sql, function (err, dbresult) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                cb([]);
            } else {
                cb(dbresult.rows);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then I call the module like this:

`db.queryPostgres(sql, function (results) {});`

Also in my package.json, I am doing `"pg": "*"` for `pg`

My query just seems to never time out no matter what I do when sending the query from the server to postgres... If I run the same query in pgAdmin, the query works and timeout since I use `set statement_timeout` Could someone help me with this? Does `connectionTimeoutMillis` even work with a `Pool`? Is there any reason why `statement_timeout` would work in pgAdmin but not work when i'm sending it from the server side of my application?

Also in my package.json, I am doing `"pg": "*"` for `pg`

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I know this question is a bit old now, but for what it is worth, have you tried setting `query_timeout`, which defaults to no timeout. ref https://node-postgres.com/api/client